# how to write this query using USING clause. i tried am getting error

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
  VENDORS.VENDOR_NAME, INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS.LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
FROM
  VENDORS, INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS
USING
  LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION;
WHERE
(INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS.LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Card%' OR 
  INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS.LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%COBAL%')
```

How should I write this query properly?

Comment: What do your tables look like?  Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Using USING, list the vendors who have supplied a line item where the description contains 'Card' or COBOL (both case insensitive). Include the vendor name and description, with no duplicate lines in the output. Order the listing by the description.

Answer (score 1):

The query you want looks something like this:

```
SELECT v.VENDOR_NAME, li.LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
FROM VENDORS v JOIN
     INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS li
     USING (VENDOR_ID)
WHERE li.LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Card%' OR 
      li.LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%COBAL%';
```

Notes:

- I am guessing what the column used for the `JOIN` really is.  I doubt it is a line item description.
- `USING` is part of the syntax for `JOIN`.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- When using `USING`, the columns for the `JOIN` are in parentheses.
- Semicolons are only at the end of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of the `;` in your `FROM` clause as pointed below

```
FROM
  VENDORS, INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS
USING
  LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION; <-- Here
WHERE ....
```

It should be

```
FROM
  VENDORS v JOIN INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS i
USING (LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION)
WHERE ....
```